# Importing txt file with 2d int array in form of str

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with a 2D array of `int`s. When I use

```
numpy.loadtxt("filename", dtype='float')
```

I get the error:

> could not convert string to float.

It is able to load the data if I use `dtype=numpy.str`, but then my array looks like

```
['1,2,3,4,5' , '6,7,8,9,10']
```

so it is an array of 2 string elements, instead a 2d array of 5 numbers per each element.

Let me know if you need me to add more details to the file.

Comment: If you just want a result, you can use np.reshape() to fix it to matrix

Comment: Use the right delimiter

Comment: Have you saved that file with numpy.savetxt ? If not, how does the file look?